# MongoDB dont use Indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Schema

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58db65b7e164191f175d12a3"),
    "supplierId" : 9,
    "resellerCode" : "k120",
    "userName" : "",
    "statusCode" : 200,
    "bookingIds" : [ 275 ],
    "stTripIds" : [],
    "mysqlId" : 3474,
    "request" : "",
    "response" : "",
    "requestTime" : ISODate("2017-01-27T15:13:46.000Z")
}
```

I have 2 indexes
1) resellerCode_1_requestTime_-1

```
{
    "resellerCode" : 1,
    "requestTime" : -1
}
```

2) supplierId_1_requestTime_-1

```
{
    "supplierId" : 1,
    "requestTime" : -1
}
```

And when I make this query

```
db.mycollection.explain('executionStats').count({ "resellerCode": "k120", "supplierId": 5 })
```

I see that Mongo use just supplierId_1_requestTime_-1 index, and use FETCH for resellerCode. I can not create covered index for resellerCode_supplierId.

Why MongoDB can not use index intersect in this case?

[image]